# Accidentally turn on silent mode

Tags: audio, silent-mode

On my LG-ally, I keep accidentally turning on silent mode.  What exactly am I doing to cause this, and is there any way to disabled whatever the action is?

Comment: If you're downvoting please explain why.  Presumably there are only a few ways to turn on silent mode, and even fewer ways to do it unintentionally on a frequent basis.. So i don't see how this question is vague or off topic

Comment: I have not voted, but your question is poorly-formed ("What exactly am I doing to cause this" - one can only guess without observing your use, and you don't even describe whether this happens in holster, pocket, or purse), and very device-dependent and therefore of limited interest.

Comment: I have a similar problem.  Whenever I mae a call on my LG Ally it automatically sets the phone in silent mode.  GAAHH!  This means that after I call one person if anyone ese cals me I won't hear the ringer.  It just started when Verizon upgraded LG Ally to 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you perhaps using the volume control and going all the way to the "bottom"? That turns on silent mode in my Droid.

Are you hitting the wrong option on the menu when you hit the power button?

I'm not familiar with the LG Ally, so I don't know if they might have added an extra feature to make it easy to get into silent mode. Did you check the manual?

Answer (score 0):

My apologies if this is too much of a me-too, but I'll second Al Everetts comments on the volume control.

I have this problem in 2 situations:
1. In the bracket I use in the car, one of the foam blocks rests a little on the down volume button.  I've since cut the foam to reduce this issue.
2. When I'm holding it in landscape mode, I often bump the volume buttons.

There are on-screen indicators though, so I *usually* don't do it without noticing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my MotoDroid, and downloaded RingGuard from the Market.  It's a simple app that detects whenever the ring volume changes and pops up an on-screen dialog to confirm.  If you don't confirm the change within a couple of seconds, it cancels it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with my new HTC touch.  I kept accidentally pressing the 'volume down' button whilst holding the phone.  After putting a gel case on the phone, this is not longer a problem, as the case covers the buttons so they're not so sensitive.